# OpenSSL fails verification of certificates exported from Windows Certificate Store

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, grpc

I need to run a CryptoAPI-based service on Windows, which loads a server-side certificate from Windows Certificates Store. I need to run a GRPC client establishing secured connection to this service. I export a corresponding CA certificate from the Windows Certificates Store, use it to configure GRPC secured channel and get authentication error.

I built a test environment with IE as a client and a custom version of the service that can handle HTTPS requests. It uses the same server-side certificate and the same CA Root certificate. In this test TLS handshake completes successfully. So it works for Windows CryptoAPI-based systems that load certificates directly from store.

I export both certificates to verify them using OpenSSL utility. The verification fails, which explains authentication error in GRPC handshake.

```
> openssl.exe verify -trusted CA.cer server.cer
CN = xyz.onebox.com
error 7 at 0 depth lookup: certificate signature failure
error server.cer: verification failed

> openssl version
OpenSSL 1.1.0l  10 Sep 2019
```

Why certificates, which used successfully by CryptoAPI-based systems, fail verification by OpenSSL?
What can be done to address this issue?